# C# - WebClient.TotalBytesToReceive is returning -1 always

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I am relatively new in C# development.

I am trying to implement a downloader using [WebClient](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/f5fe49aa-65ba-4ef9-a3b9-5ee6a2242829/why-totalbytestoreceive-is-always-1?forum=netfxnetcom).

What I have done is this-

```
private void startDownloadFile(string url)
{
    try
    {
        downloadProgress.Value = 0;
        downloadProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        //Update UI with download progress
        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += wcDownloadingString;

        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url), downloadFileLocation);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Stop the timer.
        timer.Enabled = false;
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        bDownload.IsEnabled = true;
        downloadProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}

private void wcDownloadingString(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    downloadProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

SO, I am supposed to get the UI update in progress bar, but I am not gettin that, because `e.ProgressPercentage` is returning `0` always.

It is returning `0` because, `WebClient.TotalBytesToReceive` is returning `-1` always.

[image]

My complete code can be found in here-

https://github.com/abrarjahin/wpf-Download-Manager-With-Async-Task

**Can anyone please help?**

### Re-

I have gone this places-

1. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/f5fe49aa-65ba-4ef9-a3b9-5ee6a2242829/why-totalbytestoreceive-is-always-1?forum=netfxnetcom
2. [c# WebClient DownloadProgresschanged TotalBytesToReceive = -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778423/c-sharp-webclient-downloadprogresschanged-totalbytestoreceive-1)
3. [Download file from FTP with Progress - TotalBytesToReceive is always -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591059/download-file-from-ftp-with-progress-totalbytestoreceive-is-always-1)

But can't find any solution from there.

### Re Re-

And also, server is returning the file size always, because I am implementing a web source downloader, and it is not working anywhere, so not a problem with the server.

Comment: Are you sure the server is advertising the TotalBytesToReceive? have you checked with a network sniffer such as Wireshark?

Comment: Can you please go to - https://github.com/abrarjahin/wpf-Download-Manager-With-Async-Task and check the code? I am downloading Source Code from URL